# Does *E. coli Dh5 Alpha* strain has the ability to degrade polyethylene?

Tags: molecular-biology

Does *E. coli Dh5 Alpha* strain has the ability to degrade polyethylene? What are the bacteria that can be used as a control in the research of polyethylene degradation?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any wild *E.coli* strains that have been described to have the ability to degrade polyethylene. However, work to equip *E.coli DH5α* with the ability to degrade polyethylene, by means of transformation, has been done in the laboratory ([Mahalakshmi 2012](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324656250_Genetic_Analysis_of_Plastic_Degrading_Bacterial_Strains), [Danso et al 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5881046/))

Microorganisms that can be found in the wild/nature that do have the ability to break down polyethylene include (Source: [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265408136_Screening_of_Polyethylene_Degrading_Microorganisms_from_Garbage_Soil)):

- Pseudomonas spp
- Bacillus spp
- Staphylococcus spp
- Aspergillus nidulans
- Aspergillus flavus
- Streptomyces spp